# Passing ssh options to psftp command

Tags: bash, ssh, sftp

I am using psftp to make connection between windows and linux to transfer files.

```
psftp.exe user@host -pw hello -v -bc -batch
```

However, in case of a new host above results in error:

```
Cannot confirm a host key in batch mode
FATAL ERROR: Cannot confirm a host key in batch mode
```

I want to remove `StrictHostKeyChecking` for this. Such as `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=No` in ssh or normal sftp command.

However passing `-o` doesn't work with psftp.

```
psftp.exe user@host -pw hello -v -bc -batch -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
psftp: unknown option "-o"
       try typing "psftp -h" for help
```

So, how can I pass `ssh_options` such as this, while using `psftp`?

Comment: Possible workaround:  Create a PuTTY "saved session" for the host, with the PuTTY equivalent of StrictHostKeyChecking=no in the saved session, and tell `psftp.exe` to use the saved session:  https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.79/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-pubkey

Answer (score 3):

The `StrictHostKeyChecking` is an OpenSSH directive/option. It has nothing to do with `psftp` or any other PuTTY tool.

PuTTY tools actually do not have any option equivalent to OpenSSH `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. And it's an insecure thing to do anyway.

The way to go, is either to cache the host key, or use [`-hostkey` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey) to specify a fingerprint of the expected/trusted host key.